# How to improve TTFB from Amazon S3?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, latency

I'm developing a small web app, and I have some data files stored in a s3 bucket with CORS setup that need to be accessed from the client browser.

For some reason, my ajax call to S3 files has a very high latency (over 4sec for a 7KB file), due to the TTFB (as you can see in this dev tools screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/4trx2m9m1v8visu/Screenshot%202015-08-28%2011.44.53.png?dl=1). Both the client and S3 bucket are in Northern California.

Any ideas about what might be happening here would be appreciated.

thanks

```
url = 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/simdata.zip';
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("received");
  },
  failure: function(response) {
    // TODO: decent error message
    alert('Unable to load');
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you get when you `curl`/`wget`/`ab` the file from the same network?

Answer (score 0):

4.40 s is spent on waiting, afaik that's the time spent on finding the resource on the AWS S3 servers. We don't have access to the backend of their servers.

Content Download is only 0.841s. Indicating the network transfer is excellent.

One of the recommendation that can resolve your issue is to use CDN ie. Cloudfront. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html

Alternative would be to use a small EC2 instance and put the content in memory and serve the zip file from there.

Comment: *"afaik that's the time spent on finding the resource on the AWS S3 servers"* That's speculation, and entirely unfounded, based on my experience with S3.  If you enable [access logging in S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) there is a "turnaround time" metric for each request: *The number of milliseconds that Amazon S3 spent processing your request. This value is measured from the time the last byte of your request was received until the time the first byte of the response was sent.*